# String while loop

Tags: java, string, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I need to check if the user enter a number(double) or string, everything works perfect except the last part. If the user enters "hello", the program will ask to enter the valid number but it doesn't work properly. It gives me an infinite loop unless I will enter space " ".

Here is my code:

```
double bill = 0.0;
System.out.print("Please enter the total amount of your bill > ");
  String strAmount = keysIn.nextLine();
  try {
    bill = Double.parseDouble(strAmount);
    while (bill < 0) {
        System.out.print("Your bill amount is less then 0, try again > ");
        bill = keysIn.nextDouble();
      }
  } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      while (!strAmount.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print("Enter a valid number > ");
        strAmount = keysIn.nextLine();
      }
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you just use the scanner's nextDouble function from the beginning?

Comment: It looks like Double.parseDouble(strAmout) is returning a value < 0. Are you seeing "Your bill amount is less then 0, try again > " in your console ?

Comment: Also as Niklas sugested why don't you use nextDouble()? nextLine takes the whole string

Comment: @svasa it works perfect when you first enter an input, for example -1, it will ask me to reenter the number, but if I enter string it will become a loop... I will try to use scanner from the beginning, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Scanner.nextDouble() all the time instead of once. It will only accept Doubles.

```
double bill = 0.0;
System.out.print("Please enter the total amount of your bill > ");
bill = keysIn.nextDouble();
while (bill < 0) {
    System.out.print("Your bill amount is less then 0, try again > ");
    bill = keysIn.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two while loops checking different conditions.
Try this:

```
double bill = 0.0;
System.out.print("Please enter the total amount of your bill > ");
String strAmount = keysIn.nextLine();
String numberString = strAmount.trim();

boolean invalidNumber = false;

 try {
   bill = Double.parseDouble(numberString);
 } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
   Systeout.print("Enter a valid number...");
   invalidNumber = true;
 }



while (bill < 0) {
    if(invalidNumber){
        System.out.print("Enter a valid number...");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your bill amount is less then 0, try again...");
    }
    strAmount = keysIn.nextLine();
    numberString = strAmount.trim();

    try {
        bill = Double.parseDouble(numberString);
        invalidNumber = false;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        invalidNumber = true;
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: This doesn't solve OPs Problem. You don't write to `bill`before entering the while loop. Therefore as bill is defined as `bill = 0.0` it won't even enter the loop because the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

Your infinite loop is due to `while (!strAmount.isEmpty())`, this means it will loop as long as `strAmount` is **not** empty, so remove that `!` and move the check to the end of the loop.

```
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a valid number > ");
            strAmount = keysIn.nextLine();
        } while (strAmount.isEmpty());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
double bill = 0.0;
    System.out.print("Please enter the total amount of your bill > ");
      String strAmount = keysIn.nextLine();
      boolean validated = false;

      //Validate
      while(!validated){
          try{
              bill = Double.parseDouble(strAmount);
              validated = true;
          }
          catch(NumberFormatException e) {
              System.out.print("Enter a valid number > ");
              strAmount = keysIn.nextLine();
          }
      }

      //Continue...
      while (bill < 0) {
        System.out.print("Your bill amount is less then 0, try again > ");
        bill = keysIn.nextDouble();
      }
```