# String while loop part 2

Tags: java, string, while-loop, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I've already asked similar question before: [String while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203704/string-while-loop), but now I have another issue which I can't figure out...

```
double bill = 0.0;
double tip = 0.0;

// Taking an input
System.out.print("Please enter the total amount of your bill > ");
String strBill = scan.nextLine();
boolean validatedBill = false;

  // Validating Bill
  while(!validatedBill) {
    try {
      bill = Double.parseDouble(strBill);
      validatedBill = true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.print("Enter a valid number > ");
      strBill = scan.nextLine();
    } // end of catch block
  } // end of while loop

  while(bill < 0) {
    System.out.print("Your bill amount is less then 0, try again > ");
    bill = scan.nextDouble();
  } // end of while loop

  System.out.print("Please enter the tip percentage > ");
  String strTip = scan.nextLine();
  boolean validatedTip = false;

    // Validating Tip
    while(!validatedTip) {
      try {
        tip = Double.parseDouble(strTip);
        validatedTip = true;
      } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.print("Enter a valid tip percentage > ");
        strTip = scan.nextLine();
      } // end of catch block
    } // end of while loop

    while(tip < 0) {
      System.out.print("Your tip is below 0, try again > ");
      tip = scan.nextDouble();
    } // end of while loop
```

My input works perfect, but when the program asks me to enter my tip percentage, it shows me this way:

> Please enter the tip percentage > Enter a valid tip percentage >

All in one row but at the same time it **works fine** and the program can validate strings and numbers.

The code should work this way:
1. Please enter the total amount of your bill >
2. Please enter the tip percentage >

Thanks a lot!

**Fixed code**

```
double bill = 0.0;
double tip = 0.0;

// Taking an input
System.out.print("Please enter the total amount of your bill > ");
String strBill = scan.nextLine();
boolean validatedBill = false;

  // Validating Bill
  while(!validatedBill) {
    try {
      bill = Double.parseDouble(strBill);
      validatedBill = true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.print("Enter a valid number > ");
      strBill = scan.nextLine();
    } // end of catch block
  } // end of while loop

  while(bill < 0) {
    System.out.print("Your bill amount is less then 0, try again > ");
    bill = scan.nextDouble();
  } // end of while loop
    scan.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Please enter the tip percentage > ");
  String strTip = scan.nextLine();
  boolean validatedTip = false;

    // Validating Tip
    while(!validatedTip) {
      try {
        tip = Double.parseDouble(strTip);
        validatedTip = true;
      } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.print("Enter a valid tip percentage > ");
        strTip = scan.nextLine();
      } // end of catch block
    } // end of while loop

    while(tip < 0 || tip > bill) {
      System.out.print("Your tip is less then 0 or greater then your bill, try again > ");
      tip = scan.nextDouble();
    } // end of while loop
```

Comment: You may want to use `println()` instead of `print()`.

Comment: did you try with system.out.println()

Comment: add a `scan.nextLine();` before  `System.out.print("Please enter the tip percentage > ");`. The `nextDouble()` reads a token so there is a line left by it with `nextLine()` you consume the same line rather then nextline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do

```
System.out.println("Please enter the tip percentage > ");
```

This automatically adds a newline at the end.

Alternatively, you could do.

```
System.out.print("Please enter the total amount of your bill > \n");
String strBill = scan.nextLine();
boolean validatedBill = false;

  // Validating Bill
  while(!validatedBill) {
    try {
      bill = Double.parseDouble(strBill);
      validatedBill = true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.print("Enter a valid number > \n");
      strBill = scan.nextLine();
    } // end of catch block
  } // end of while loop
```

More info on [`System.out.println()`](http://javapapers.com/core-java/system-out-println/)

Or for your full code:

```
double bill = 0.0;
double tip = 0.0;

// Taking an input
System.out.println("Please enter the total amount of your bill > ");
String strBill = scan.nextLine();
boolean validatedBill = false;

  // Validating Bill
  while(!validatedBill) {
    try {
      bill = Double.parseDouble(strBill);
      validatedBill = true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("Enter a valid number > ");
      strBill = scan.nextLine();
    } // end of catch block
  } // end of while loop

  while(bill < 0) {
    System.out.println("Your bill amount is less then 0, try again > ");
    bill = scan.nextDouble();
  } // end of while loop

  System.out.println("Please enter the tip percentage > ");
  String strTip = scan.nextLine();
  boolean validatedTip = false;

    // Validating Tip
    while(!validatedTip) {
      try {
        tip = Double.parseDouble(strTip);
        validatedTip = true;
      } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Enter a valid tip percentage > ");
        strTip = scan.nextLine();
      } // end of catch block
    } // end of while loop

    while(tip < 0) {
      System.out.println("Your tip is below 0, try again > ");
      tip = scan.nextDouble();
    } // end of while loop
```

Comment: Right, but it should work this way: 
1. Ask about your bill
2. Ask about your tip

Comment: In my case it asks two different questions at a time

Comment: @S.Anthony Glad to help.  If my answer answered your question, you can mark it as such by pressing the checkmark.